# How to send notifications through android app to all users installed and registered that android app?

Tags: android

Can anyone help me with a way to send requests as a notification through my android app to all the users who have installed my application and then their responses are sent back to the user who sent the request.

I have read about GCM but I dont understand how can I register all the users to get their GCM registration ID and how can i simulataneously send a notification to all users..I may sound naive but I am completely new to this GCM concept and I dont think that it is the exact thing what I am looking for..

So,somebody please tell me how to send notifications(simultaneously on click of a button or something..) to all the users who have registered in my android app .

Comment: You have to provide, what have you tried, and which part fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to build a server component that keeps track of all registered users.  This component will be an app that you write and expose in the cloud.  There are many app-hosting services to choose from.  Amazon EC2 is one example.

So the app flow would be something like this:

1. User launches your Android app.
2. Android app registers itself with GMC.  GCM will respond with a token that represents that device.
3. Android app POSTs that device token to your cloud application.
4. Cloud application saves that token.  The app should now have a list of tokens that represents all active devices running your app.  (of course you may want to have an expiration policy - i.e. remove all tokens corresponding to devices you have not heard from in say 30 days).
5. One of your app users posts a message that s/he wants to broadcast.
6. Your Android app responds by sending a request to your cloud application.
7. Your cloud application responds to this request, by making a request to GCM.  In this request (or series of requests), the app will include all device tokens and the user-entered message.
8. GCM responds by pushing the message to all devices with your app (i.e. all of those that have register with GCM and received a token - see step 2).

Answer (score 0):

If using GCM alone you would need to write a server component. I get the impression you don't want to do this. You could use Urban Airship push messaging, which will allow you to send out a message to all registered apps from the Urban Airship web portal. Urban Airship integrates with GCM (which is easy to setup). You would still need to add code to your app to handle the push notification the app receives.

http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/android.html